# is it possible to search for a range on Strings in sqlalchemy

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sqlalchemy, range

I have a table that has HOUSENUM as a String.  Numbers can be 200 or 200A (number with an apt. letter).  I need to filter results from the table using a range of house numbers, ie. 100-450.
Just to start out I tried:

```
request=request.filter(table.HOUSENUM.between ('100', '450'))
```

which returns everything.

The letters added to the number make it even more challenging.  Any idea of how I might get all numbers between the range?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to do what I wanted in sqlalchemy so I added a column to my table in MSSQL using the following code base:

```
Declare @X     varchar(100)
Select     @X=    '11AA'

select 
cast(
case  
    WHEN @x NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'   THEN 0 --Needed to check if accidental letters only
    when SubString(@X,0,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@X))> 0  --returns 0 if no letters after number
    then SubString(@X,0,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@X))  -- returns just numbers if letters after number
    else @X
end
  as int)
     as number 

--// shows result '11'
```

if you have letters before the number, you can use the following to strip letters before numbers: SubString(@X,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@X),Len(@X))

Derived from post: http://forums.asp.net/post/1035324.aspx